# Why can't I assign to an lambda-syntax read-only property in the constructor?

Tags: c#

My case:

```
public class A
{
    public string _prop { get; }
    public A(string prop)
    {
        _prop = prop; // allowed
    }
}
```

Another case:

```
public class A
{
    public string _prop => string.Empty;
    public A(string prop)
    {
        // Property or indexer 'A._prop' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
        _prop = prop;
    }
}
```

Both syntax:

```
public string _prop { get; }
```

and

```
 public string _prop => string.Empty;
```

create a read only property. But why coundn't I assign it in the second case?

Comment: There's also `public string Prop { get; } = string.Empty;` to initialize read-only auto-implemented properties.

Comment: Finally, I wrote an article: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/09/13/Varieties-of-properties.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public string _prop => string.Empty;
```

is equal to:

```
public string _prop { get { return string.Empty; } }
```

So, `string.Empty` is like method code in method `get`.

```
public string _prop { get; }
```

is equal to:

```
private readonly string get_prop;
public string _prop { get { return get_prop;} }
```

So, you can assign `get_prop` a value from constructor;

More information in [the article](http://blog.rogatnev.net/2017/09/13/Varieties-of-properties.html).